# fragment is overlapping on activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

The fragment is overlapping over activity. Views inside them are overlapping. I tried changing the background color of the fragment but it didn't work. It only changes background color but all views inside activity are displayed over the fragment.

Comment: can you share  code ?

Comment: @vin Tigadi add your xml file for fragment and actvity